# (matlab) MLP with relu and softmax not working with mini-batch SGD and produces similar predictions on MNIST dataset

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network, softmax, reluctant-quantifiers

I implemented a multilayer perceptron with 1 hidden layer on MNIST dataset. The activation function in hidden layer is leaky(0.01) ReLu and output layer has a softmax activation function. The learning method is mini-batch SGD. The network structure is 784*30*10. The problem is I found the predictions the network made, for each input sample, are quite similar. That means the model would always like to think the image is some certain number. Thanks @Lemm Ras for pointing out the label-data mismatching problem in previous data_shuffle function and now fixed. But after some batch training, I found the predictions are still some kind of similar: [image] That's confusing.

Another issue is the update value is too small comparing with original weight, in the MLP code, I add variable 'cc' and 'dd' to record the ratio between their weight_update and weight,

```
cc=W_OUTPUT_Update./W_OUTPUT;
dd=W_MLP_Update./W_MLP;
```

During debugging, the magnitude for cc is 10^-4(0.0001) and dd is also 10^-4. This might be the reason that [the accuracy doesn't seems improved a lot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsfbT.jpg)

After several days debugging. I have no idea why that happens and how to solve it, it made me stuck for one week. Can someone help me please?
The screenshot is the value of A2 after softmax function.

```
[dimension, images, labels, labels_matrix, train_amount, test_labels_matrix, test_images, test_labels, test_amount] = load_mnist_data(); %initialize str
    images=images(:,1:10000); % for debugging, get part of whole data set
    labels=labels(1:10000,1);
    labels_matrix=labels_matrix(:,1:10000);
    test_images=test_images(:,1:500);
    test_labels=test_labels(1:500,1);
    train_amount=10000;
    test_amount=500;
    % initialize the structure
    [ W_MAD, W_MLP, W_OUTPUT] = initialize_structure(dimension, train_amount, test_amount);



epoch=100;
correct_rate=zeros(1,epoch); %record testing accuracy
corr=zeros(1,epoch);    %record training accuracy
lr=0.2;
lamda=0;
batch_size=50;


for i=1:epoch
    sprintf('MLP in iteration %d over %d', i, epoch)
    %shuffle data
    [labels_shuffled labels_matrix_shuffled images_shuffled]=shuffle_data(labels, labels_matrix,images);
     [ cor, W_MLP, W_OUTPUT ] = train_mlp_relu(lr, leaky, lamda, momentum_gamma, batch_size,W_MLP, W_OUTPUT, W_MAD, power, images_shuffled, train_amount, labels_shuffled, labels_matrix_shuffled);

    corr(i)=cor/train_amount;
    % test 
    correct_rate(i) = structure_test(  W_MAD, W_MLP, W_OUTPUT, test_images, test_labels, test_amount );
end

% plot results
plot(1:epoch,correct_rate);
```

Here's the training MLP function, please ignore L2 regularization parameter lamda which is currently set as 0.

```
%MLP with batch size batch_size
    cor=0;
    %leaky=(1/batch_size);
    leaky=0.001;
    for i=1:train_amount/batch_size
        batch_images=images(:,batch_size*(i-1)+1:batch_size*i);
        batch_labels=labels_matrix(:,batch_size*(i-1)+1:batch_size*i);
        %from MAD to MLP

        V1=W_MLP'*batch_images;
        V1(1,:)=1; %set bias unit as 1
        V1_dirivative=ones(size(V1));
        V1_dirivative(find(V1<0))=leaky;
        A1=relu(V1,leaky); % A stands for activation
        V2=W_OUTPUT'* A1;
        A2=softmax(V2);
        %write these scope control codes into functions.
        %train error
        [val idx]=max(A2);
        idx=idx-1; %because  index(idx) for matrix vaires from 1 to 10 while label varies from 0 to 9.


        res=labels(batch_size*(i-1)+1:batch_size*i)-idx';
        cor=cor+sum(res(:)==0);
        %softmax loss, due to relu applied nodes that has
        %contribution to activate neurons has gradient 1; while <0 nodes
        %has no contribution
        delta_softmax=-(1/batch_size)*(batch_labels-A2);
        delta_output=W_OUTPUT*delta_softmax.*V1_dirivative;
        %update
        W_OUTPUT_Update=lr*(1/batch_size)*A1*delta_softmax'+lamda*W_OUTPUT;

        cc=W_OUTPUT_Update./W_OUTPUT;


        W_MLP_Update=lr*(1/batch_size)*batch_images*delta_output'+lamda*W_MLP;       

        dd=W_MLP_Update./W_MLP;

        k=mean(A2,2);
        W_OUTPUT=W_OUTPUT-W_OUTPUT_Update;
        W_MLP=W_MLP-W_MLP_Update;
    end
end
```

Here is the softmax function:

```
function [ val ] = softmax( val )
    val=exp(val);
    val=val./repmat(sum(val),10,1);
end
```

The labels_matrix is the aimed output matrix for A2 and created as:

```
   labels_matrix=full(sparse(labels+1,1:train_amount,1));
   test_labels_matrix=full(sparse(test_labels+1,1:test_amount,1));
```

And Relu:

```
function [ val ] = relu( val,leaky )
    val(find(val<0))=leaky*val(find(val<0));
end
```

Data shuffle

```
    %this version is wrong, due to it only shuffles label and data without doing the same shuffling on the 'labels_matrix' which is used to calculate MLP's delta in output layer. It destroyed the link between data and label.

%    function [ label, data ] = shuffle_data( label, data )
%        [row column]=size(data);
%        array=randperm(column);
%        data=data(:,array);
%        label=label(array);
%        %if shuffle respect to row then use the code below
%        %data=data(randperm(row),:);
%    end

function [ label, label_matrix, data ] = shuffle_data( label, label_matrix, data  )
    [row column]=size(data);
    array=randperm(column);
    data=data(:,array);
    label=label(array);
    label_matrix=label_matrix(:, array);
    %if shuffle respect to row then use the code below
    %data=data(randperm(row),:);
end
```

Data loading:

```
function [ dimension, images, labels, labels_matrix, train_amount, test_labels_matrix, test_images, test_labels, test_amount] = load_mnist_data()
    %%load training and testing data, labels
        data_location='C:\Users\yz39g15\Documents\MATLAB\common\mnist test\for the report/modify/train-images.idx3-ubyte';
        label_location='C:\Users\yz39g15\Documents\MATLAB\common\mnist test\for the report/modify/train-labels.idx1-ubyte';
        test_data_location='C:\Users\yz39g15\Documents\MATLAB\common\mnist test\for the report/modify/t10k-images.idx3-ubyte';
        test_label_location='C:\Users\yz39g15\Documents\MATLAB\common\mnist test\for the report/modify/t10k-labels.idx1-ubyte';
        images = loadMNISTImages(data_location);
        labels = loadMNISTLabels(label_location);
        test_images=loadMNISTImages(test_data_location);
        test_labels=loadMNISTLabels(test_label_location);
    %%data centralization
        [dimension train_amount]=size(images);
        [dimension test_amount]=size(test_images);


    %%complete normalization
    %%transform labels from index to matrix in order to apply square loss function in output layer
        labels_matrix=full(sparse(labels+1,1:train_amount,1));
        test_labels_matrix=full(sparse(test_labels+1,1:test_amount,1));        
end
```

Comment: About the ratio, have you tried to increase the learning rate?

Comment: Yes, I tried different magnitude from 0.01,0.1 1 and 10, found the curve for 0.01 is relatively better. I'm writing a function to manually calculate gradient. With that function I just make a comparison with the gradient which is given by formula in the code. It turns out, for the gradient in `W_OUTPUT`, they are quite different, I mean the magnitude is different. I'm currently not sure I wrote it right, I'll get back asap and update the code after I confirm its correctness.

Comment: @LemmRas, I found it this afternoon, the issue is the shuffle_data function, after I commented that code, it works. I added L2 regularization and tuning other parameters and got a 97% training error, 96 testing error. I'll figure out how to make the shuffle working tomorrow.

Comment: I think you could try to not shuffle with respect to rows or columns, but adding a third dimension and shuffling with respect to it. Otherwise the images are not preserved.

Comment: @LemmRas I found the bug, the shuffle function only works on label and data but not the 'labels_matrix' which is used to calculate delta value in MLP's output layer, that is why the shuffle doesn't actually and break the association between label and data, cheers mate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are shuffling the images, the association data-label is lost. Since this association must survive, what you need is to enforce the same shuffling for both data and labels.

In order to do so you could, for instance, Create an external shuffled index list: `shuffled=randperm(N)`, with N the number of images and then pass to the train method either the list created or the elements of  `images` and `label` addressed by the shuffled list.